# Running multiple adb shell commands in batch file

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, root

I am making a batch file which would do this for N devices
mount -o rw, remount /system
and send .jar file to /system/framework/ on a rooted devices
Currently I have something like

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb disconnect
ECHO "Connecting"
adb connect 192.168.4.17
adb connect 192.168.4.17
adb connect 192.168.4.17
adb connect 192.168.4.17
ECHO "Connected"
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"
ECHO "Mounting /system sucessfully, copying.jar"
timeout 5
adb push android.policy.jar /system/framework/
ECHO "Restarting device!"
timeout 5
adb reboot
ECHO "DONE"
```

And then I would just copy this lines like N amount of times in 1 batch file and just change IP.
The problem is that I cannot run

```
"adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

Because it says
"su: su successfully
su: exec failed for mount -o rw,remount /system Error:No such file or directory"

If I try any other case of running multiple commands in adb shell it just breaks batch file and it doesn't work, I've also tried

```
adb shell "su & mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

but with no luck.

How could I run a batch script which would update multiple rooted devices, so that I could just change IP?
Ty in advance!

Comment: In linux this works: adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system". Device Android 4+. Maybe problem with device or with adb/su versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start with a batch that will update single android device based on IP without problems. Right now it seems there are some issues with `mount`. After this add `FOR` that will read IPs from the batch command line parameters.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do (
    echo updating ip %%a
    // YOUR BATCH GOES HERE
)
```

Run like this: `update.bat 192.168.4.1 192.168.4.2 192.168.4.3`. 
Note that your devices will be updated sequentially.

Alternatively you could put IPs into text file and read them with `FOR /F`.

Comment: reread question. Problem not in adding IP's. Problem in "adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"

Comment: You are right, I somehow focused on batch part of the question. Will delete answer if appropriate.