# Android: Running multiple adb commands using batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, automation

I have to execute multiple test on my AVD and that too using `adb shell` command somewhat like

```
/Users/roger/AndroidSDK/sdk/platform-tools/./adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.demo.test.MyTest1 com.demo.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

/Users/roger/AndroidSDK/sdk/platform-tools/./adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.demo.test.MyTest2 com.demo.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Now, assuming currently both the test are created as a separate project and test apk is installed onto the virtual device. I have to execute these test using a java project.

I am using mac, so I created a shell script `mytestscript.sh` and wrote a java program to execute the script like below:

```
 public static String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // use logger
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

And this is how I am invoking the method `executeCommand("sh scripts/mytestscript.sh");`

The problem I am facing here is when I move to windows system as I have to schedule this job on windows machine. Having to create a `.bat` file to execute these command something like this:

```
executeCommand("cmd /c start scripts\\mytestscript.bat");
```

Now, this opens the cmd terminal on windows and executes the first command but after the test finishes, the second command is not executed. I have to manually close the terminal and then the second command executes which is not desired.

Is there a way to achieve this? How can I execute multiple commands using batch files for android in windows? Any alterative way to execute `.sh` scripts on windows?

I have gone through [Running multiple adb shell commands in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039769/running-multiple-adb-shell-commands-in-batch-file) but it is different than what I desire.